# SQL Query All Columns Using Distinct on One Column Only

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to select all columns of a table with ONLY ONE column distinct

The table is

| subCode | Title | grade | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 045/01 | Math | 12 | Grade 12.D |
| 045/01 | Math | 12 | Grade 12.C |
| 045/01 | Math | 12 | Grade 12.A |
| 011/01 | Science | 12 | Grade 12.D |
| 011/01 | Science | 12 | Grade 12.C |

I want to select DISTINCT subCode with the corresponding Title, grade and section

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subCode ,Title, grade, section FROM TABLENAME;
```

but it did not return what I want.

I want it to return :

| subCode | Title | grade | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 045/01 | Math | 12 | Grade 12.D |
| 011/01 | Science | 12 | Grade 12.D |

Comment: What is the logic by which these two rows are being retained?

Comment: add  end of line GROUP BY subCode;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to group by columns `subCode ,Title, grade` to keep them non-aggregated, while apply aggregation for `section` such as

```
SELECT subCode ,Title, grade, MAX(section) AS section 
  FROM TABLENAME
 GROUP BY subCode ,Title, grade
```

You should be getting 5 rows with or without `DISTINCT` keyword in the current case. Since the combination of the columns differ for each row.